# Unfortunately, Project1 has stopped. Android error while inserting to MongoDB

Tags: android, mongodb, android-studio

I am trying to insert data into MongoDB from my Android application. For this I have written this code (given below) but this code pops-up an error when I click save button (for inserting data into MongoDB).

**Error:** `Unfortunately, Project1 has stopped.`

So what is the problem in this code and how can I solve that problem?

**Code behind insert/save button:**

```
Task save_task = new Task();
save_task.date = showDate.getText().toString();
save_task.location = showLocation.getText().toString();
save_task.description = note.getText().toString();

SaveAsyncTask tsk = new SaveAsyncTask(SetNotification.this);
tsk.execute(save_task);
```

**Task.java Class:**

```
package com.example.abc.project1;

/**
 * Created by abc on 02-May-16.
 */
public class Task {

    public String date;
    public String location;
    public String description;
}
```

**SaveAsyncTask.java Class:**

```
package com.example.abc.project1.MongoHQ;

/**
 * Created by abc on 02-May-16.
 */
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.abc.project1.SetNotification;
import com.example.abc.project1.Task;

public class SaveAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Task, Void, Boolean> {

    private static Context context;
    public SaveAsyncTask(Context c) {
        context = c;
    }


    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Task... arg0) {
        try {

            Task task = arg0[0];

            QueryBuilder qb = new QueryBuilder();

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost request = new HttpPost(qb.buildContactsSaveURL());

            StringEntity params =new StringEntity(qb.createTask(task));
            request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
            request.setEntity(params);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

            if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()<205)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

**QueryBuilder.java Class:**

```
package com.example.abc.project1.MongoHQ;

import com.example.abc.project1.Task;

/**
 * Created by abc on 02-May-16.
 */

public class QueryBuilder {

        /**
         * Specify your database name here
         * @return
         */
        public String getDatabaseName() {
            return "location_notification";
        }

        /**
         * Specify your MongoLab API here
         * @return
         */
        public String getApiKey() {
            return "#########";
        }

        /**
         * This constructs the URL that allows you to manage your database,
         * collections and documents
         * @return
         */
        public String getBaseUrl()
        {
            return "https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/"+getDatabaseName()+"/collections/";
        }

        /**
         * Completes the formating of your URL and adds your API key at the end
         * @return
         */
        public String docApiKeyUrl()
        {
            return "?apiKey="+getApiKey();
        }

        /**
         * Returns the tasks collection
         * @return
         */
        public String documentRequest()
        {
            return "tasks";
        }

        /**
         * Builds a complete URL using the methods specified above
         * @return
         */
        public String buildContactsSaveURL()
        {
            return getBaseUrl()+documentRequest()+docApiKeyUrl();
        }

        /**
         * Formats the contact details for MongoHQ Posting
         * @param : Details of the Task
         * @return
         */
        public String createTask(Task task)
        {
            return String
                    .format("{\"document\"  : {\"date\": \"%s\", "
                                    + "\"location\": \"%s\", \"description\": \"%s\"}, \"safe\" : true}",
                            task.date, task.location, task.description);
        }



}
```

Comment: `DefaultHttpClient` is deprecated then why you are use it ?

Comment: Please post your log also